# How do I set an environment variable based on the output of a command?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Within a `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)"
```

This does not result in the `lsb_release -c -s` command being substituted.

```
RUN export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)"
```

Does not work either.

How can I achieve the the above?